Django generated html arrangement differs
I don't understand, why are those two arrangement different?
I think, load by django templates, different, but I can't find it where is it.
post_list's side widget things is right position,
but post_detail isn't
could you please let me know, how can it be solves?
Also if you can teach to me, not just solve. Why when something is wrong, how can I watching and adjust by myself tags by so many tags.
post_list (right)

post_detail (wrong)



<!-- post_list.html -->

{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block main_area %}

    <!-- Blog post 쓰기 버튼   -->
    <!-- admin이나 staff 부여받은 사람만 글쓰기 가능   -->
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        {% if user.is_superuser or user.is_staff %}
            <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm float-right" href="/blog/create_post/" role="button">
                <i class="fas fa-pen"></i>&nbsp;New Post
            </a>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
<h1>
    Blog {% if category %}<span class="badge badge-secondary">{{ category }}</span>{% endif %}
    {% if tag %}<span class="badge badge-light"><i class="fas fa-tags"></i>{{ tag }} ({{ tag.post_set.count }})</span>{% endif %}
</h1>

{% if post_list.exists %}

{% for p in post_list %}
<!-- Blog post-->
<div class="card mb-4" id="post-{{ p.pk }}">
    {% if p.head_image %}
    <a href="{{ p.head_image.url }}"><img class="card-img-top" src="{{ p.head_image.url }}"
                                          alt="{{ p }} head_image"/></a>
    {% else %}
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/{{ p.pk }}/800/200" alt="random_image">
    {% endif %}
    <div class="card-body">
        {% if p.category %}
            <span class="badge badge-secondary float-right">{{ p.category }}</span>
        {% else %}
            <span class="badge badge-secondary float-right">미분류</span>
        {% endif %}
        <h2 class="card-title">{{ p.title}}</h2>
        {% if p.hook_text %}
        <h5 class="text-muted">{{ p.hook_text }}</h5>
        {% endif %}
        <p class="card-text">{{ p.get_content_markdown | truncatewords_html:45 | safe }}</p>

        {% if p.tags.exists %}
            <i class="fas fa-tags"></i>
            {% for tag in p.tags.iterator %}
                <a href="{{ tag.get_absolute_url }}"><span class="badge badge-pill badge-light">
                    {{ tag }}
                </span></a>
            {% endfor %}
            <br>
            <br>
        {% endif %}

        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ p.get_absolute_url }}">Read more &rarr;</a>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer text-muted">
        Posted on {{ p.created_at }} by
        <a href="#">{{ p.author | upper }}</a>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
<h3>아직 게시물이 없습니다.</h3>
{% endif %}

<!-- Pagination -->
<ul class="pagination justify-content-center mb-4">
    <li class="page-item">
        <a href="#" class="page-link">&larr; Privious</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item disabled">
        <a href="#" class="page-link">Next &rarr;</a>
    </li>
</ul>
{% endblock %}





<!-- post_detail.html -->

{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block head_title %}
{{ post.title }} - Blog
{% endblock %}

{% block main_area %}

<div id="post-area">
    <!-- category -->
    {% if post.category %}
    <span class="badge badge-secondary float-right">{{ post.category }}</span>
    {% else %}
    <span class="badge badge-secondary float-right">미분류</span>
    {% endif %}
    <!-- Post title-->
    <h1 class="mt-4">{{ post.title }}</h1>
    <h5 class="text-muted">{{ post.hook_text }}</h5>

    <!-- Author -->
    <p class="lead">by <a href="#">{{ post.author | upper }}</a></p>
    <hr>
    <!-- Edit post button       -->
    {% if user.is_authenticated and user == post.author %}
    <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm float-right" href="/blog/update_post/{{ post.pk }}/" role="button">
        <i class="fas fa-pen"> Edit Post</i>
    </a>
    {% endif %}

    <!-- Date/Time -->
    <p>{{ post.created_at }}</p>
    <hr>
    <!-- Preview Image -->
    {% if post.head_image %}
    <img src="{{ post.head_image.url }}" class="img-fluid rounded" alt="{{ post.title }} head_image">
    {% else %}
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/{{ post.id }}/800/200" alt="random_image">
    {% endif %}
    <hr>

    <!-- post Content -->
    <p>{{ post.get_content_markdown | safe }}</p>

    {% if post.tags.exists %}
    <i class="fas fa-tags"></i>
    {% for tag in post.tags.all %}
    <a href="{{ tag.get_absolute_url }}" class="badge badge-light">{{ tag }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
    <br>
    <br>
    {% endif %}

    {% if post.file_upload %}
    <a href="{{ post.file_upload.url }}" class="btn btn-success" role="button" download>Download:
        {% if post.get_file_ext == 'csv' %}
        <i class="fa-solid fa-file-csv"></i>
        {% elif post.get_file_ext == 'xlsx' or post.get_file_ext == 'xls' %}
        <i class="fa-solid fa-file-excel"></i>
        {% elif post.get_file_ext == 'docx' or post.get_file_ext == 'doc' %}
        <i class="fa-solid fa-file-word"></i>
        {% else %}
        <i class="fa-solid fa-file"></i>
        {% endif %}
        {{ post.get_file_name }}
    </a>
    {% endif %}
    <hr>
</div>

<!-- Comment area   -->
<div id="comment-area">
    <!-- Comments section-->
    <div class="mb-4">
        <h5 class="card-header">Leave a Comment:</h5>
        <div class="card-body">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <!-- Comment form-->
            <form id="comment-form" method="POST" action="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}" new_comment/>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ comment_form | crispy }}
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
            {% else %}
            <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-block btn-sm" href="#" data-toggle="modal"
               data-target="#loginModal">Log in and leave a comment</a>
            {% endif %}

            <!-- comment roop -->
            {% if post.comment_set.exists %}
            {% for comment in post.comment_set.iterator %}
            <!--  Single Comment  -->
            <div class="media mb-4" id="comment-{{ comment.pk }}">
                <img class="d-flex mr-3 rounded-circle" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <!-- 로그인한 작성자여야 댓글 작성 가능하게하는 기능 -->
                    {% if user.is_authenticated and comment.author == user %}
                    <div class="float-right">
                        <a role="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info"
                           id="comment-{{ comment.pk }}-update-btn" href="/blog/update_comment/{{ comment.pk }}/">
                            Edit
                        </a>
                        <a role="button" href="#" id="comment-{{ comment.pk }}-delete-modal-btn"
                           class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-toggle="modal"
                           data-target="#deleteCommentModal-{{ comment.pk }}">
                            Delete
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="deleteCommentModal-{{ comment.pk }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
                         aria-labelledby="deleteCommentModalLabel"
                         aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleteModalLabel">Are you Sure?</h5>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <del>{{ comment | linebreaks }}</del>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                    <a role="button" class="btn btn-danger"
                                       href="/blog/delete_comment/{{ comment.pk }}/">Delete</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    {% endif %}
                    <h5 class="mt-0">
                        {{ comment.author.username }} &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <small class="text-muted">{{ comment.created_at }}</small>
                    </h5>
                    <p>{{ comment.content | linebreaks }}</p>

                    <!-- created_at과 modified를 대조해서, 새로 생성 된 것이면, create, 기존에 있는 것이라면, modify로 노출한다. -->
                    {% if comment.created_at != comment.modified_at %}
                    <p class="text-muted float-right"><small>Updated: {{ comment.modified_at }}</small></p>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}




Please visit [ask] and create a [mcve] - your snippets are not runnable and do not have any CSS
